# How can I use name of string instead of content of string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, getstring

Normally, I use

```
String[] arrayName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name_array);
```

So are there any ways to use

```
String[] arrayName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NAME);
```

with NAME is string (`String NAME = "name_array";`)?

Answer (score 0):

Android replace string name to integer id after compile, but you place id to varialbe

```
int NAME = R.array.name_array;
String[] arrayName = getResources().getStringArray(NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by what is in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getStringArray(int)), this is an acceptable way of referencing your array. However, I need to point out an error in your flow:

- NAME must be an int. Therefore, the value should be R.id.name_array (this would return an *int*). Also, remove the double quotes around `name_array`.

You can do the referencing this way:

```
int NAME = R.array.name_array; // use a variable to store the int reference
String[] arrayName = getResources().getStringArray(NAME); //fetch
```